# Fetching JSON data using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to populate a div using ajax.Here goes the code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/assets/location.php",
    //dataType:"json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("hello");

        $.each(result, function (i, val) {
            alert("hello");
            alert(val.title);
        });
    }
});
```

server

```
<?php
require_once 'include.php';

$db = connect_db();
$query = 'CALL get_location()';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($data, $row);
}

echo(json_encode($data));
?>
```

Everything works fine but when I uncomment dataType:"json" script stops executing success function.
Please point out the errors.

Comment: Is your json formatted correctly? When you add dataType:json, success callback is not called when there is an error in parsing the response. And also you wont need JSON.parse , jquery will do it automatically for you.

Comment: I am new to web development so I don't know it well.Read somewhere that I should use JSON.parse to make code work in chrome  :( :(

Comment: Thats right, you will need JSON.parse when you dont have dataType: json. But when you have it jQuery will automatically parse the json response and pass the JSON object to your success callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your success function includes the expression `JSON.parse(result)`.

With `dataType:"json"` uncommented, jQuery automatically json-decodes the data.

Therefore, `JSON.parse(result)` will try to  decode something that's already decoded.

I'm guessing you get a parse error. Check your console.

Answer (score 0):

Without `dataType:'json'` option, your code should be.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/assets/location.php",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("hello");

        //data is not parsed, so you have to explicitly parse to json
        $.each(JSON.parse(result), function (i, val) {
            alert("hello");
            alert(val.title);
        });
    }
});
```

With `dataType:'json'` option, your code should be.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "/assets/location.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert("hello");

            //result is already parsed to json (by dataType option), 
            //So no need to parse again.
            $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                alert("hello");
                alert(val.title);
            });
        }
    });
```